# JRJC Java client issue

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to connect to JIRA and use the JIRA Query Language (JQL) to find the latest projects. I got this example and am trying to connect with the the URL https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/latest/search and my credentials, but I get an error. Most of the examples show `localhost` as the connection URL. The credentials I used are my credentials for log in (which works fine for the website).

This is the error stack:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri: https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/latest/search/rest/api/latest/user?username=rabaner&amp;expand=groups</message></status>
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:167)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:159)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:48)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:12)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:285)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:162)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:799)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:175)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:285)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:162)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:799)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:175)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message></message></status>
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:266)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.extractErrors(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:202)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:164)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the incorrect URL. It should be:

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/latest/user?username=rabaner&amp;expand=groups
```

Fixing it I received:

```
{"self":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=rabaner","key":"rabaner","name":"rabaner","emailAddress":"ranjanbanerjee5 at gmail dot com","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10452","24x24":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10452","16x16":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10452","32x32":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10452"},"displayName":"Ranjan Banerjee","active":true,"timeZone":"Etc/UTC","groups":{"size":1,"items":[]},"expand":"groups"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It has solved my issue. Appreciate your help:)